# Css negation giving type error

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In my model I have

```
self.isAssetForTradingEnabled = false;
```

and when I try to bind it to add some style like this:

```html
<tr data-bind="css: { 'selected': quantity() > 0 , 'disabled': !isAssetForTradingEnabled() }">
```

Then Knockout gives a type error.

It works if I change

```
isAssetForTradingEnabled = true;
```

and

```
'disabled': isAssetForTradingEnabled
```

Comment: try this `'disabled': !isAssetForTradingEnabled` . As far i see its not observable so you cant use `()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have this...

```
self.isAssetForTradingEnabled = false;
```

...you should not do this...

```
'disabled': !isAssetForTradingEnabled()
```

...because `isAssetForTradingEnabled` is not a(n observable) function. Instead either do this...

```
'disabled': !isAssetForTradingEnabled
```

...or change your view model to this...

```
self.isAssetForTradingEnabled = ko.observable(false);
```

Note that you need the latter if you want the view to respond to changes in `isAssetForTradingEnabled`, because plain (non-observable) members aren't tracked.